# JQuery Mouse Event Trigger If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a binding that I want to control a bit better.. Here's the code first off:

```
 $('#topnav').bind({

                            mouseenter: function() {
                                $("#topnav").animate({opacity: 1.0, width: '98%', height: '38px'});
                            },
                            mouseleave: function() {
                                   $("#topnav").delay(2000).animate({opacity: 0.9, width: '310px', height: '33px'});
                            }

                            });
```

Currently you see I am delaying the mouseleave because the navbar the person is "mouseenter-ing" is very small, and if the mouse happens to leave for a split second, it triggers the mouseleave event. I want to control that a bit better. I want some type of if statement that says "if the mouse leaves the #topnav div for less than three seconds and re-enters, pretend the mouse never even left"

If this does not make sense I will clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: @MattBall I'd really like a Jquery version instead of having another script to control that. Thank you though

Comment: HoverIntent is a jQuery plugin. That means it _is_ jQuery. You want us to reinvent the wheel for you instead? This has been solved and is no longer a remotely interesting problem. I'll pass; enjoy your evening.

Comment: @MattBall look below. No reinvention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()`:

```
var tout;
$('#topnav').bind({
  mouseenter: function() {
    clearTimeout(tout);
    $("#topnav").animate({opacity: 1.0, width: '98%', height: '38px'});
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    tout = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#topnav").animate({opacity: 0.9, width: '310px', height: '33px'});
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Comment: @ScottS Thank you, works like a dream. Thanks for your simple answer!

Answer (score 0):

make use of setTimeout() and clearTimeout()

```
var timeout = null
var onMouseEnter = function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout)
  $("#topnav").animate({opacity: 1.0, width: '98%', height: '38px'}) 
}

var onMouseLeave = function(){
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#topnav").animate({opacity: 0.9, width: '310px', height: '33px'});
  },1000)
}

$('#topnav').bind({ mouseenter: onMouseEnter, mouseleave: onMouseLeave })​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmhLZ/